# Constructing a regular measure from a set-function of open sets

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures

If a set-function $\mu'$ with certain properties (not important here) is defined on the set $K(X)$ of compact subsets of a topological space $X$, a regular measure $\mu$ can be constructed such that $\mu(K) = \mu'(K) \ \forall K \in K(X)$.

> My question is: is it possible to construct a positive bounded regular measure $\mu$ from a positive bounded set-function $\mu'$ defined on the set $O(X)$ of open subsets of a topological space $X$ such that $\mu(O) = \mu'(O) \ \forall O \in O(X)$? If so, what properties should $\mu'$ have?

I believe that the definition should be $\mu (S) = \inf _{S \subseteq O} \mu'(O)$, the infimum being taken over all open subsets $O$ containing $S$, but I am interested in the possibility (and general idea) of the construction.

Comment: The usual theorem here is Caratheodory extension: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem. For regularity we have that if $\mu$ is finite and, or $X$ is polish or $X$ is $\sigma$-compact metrizable, then $\mu$ is regular. Maybe these comments are useful to you

Comment: @VeridianDynamics: The set of all open subsets is not a ring, therefore Caratheodory's theorem might not help here - or, at least, not immediately. Regularity should be trivial, since it is contained in the construction itself.

Comment: The necessary conditions for $\mu’$ are the following. Let $O,O’\in O(X)$  be arbitrary sets. If $O\subset O’$ then $\mu’(O)\le \mu’(O’)$. If $O$ and $O’$ are disjoint then $\mu’(O\cup O’)=\mu’(O)+\mu’(O’)$. If we require that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive then the previous equality should hold for countable unions of mutually disjoint members of $O(X)$. Also I guess we may need that if $\{O_n\}$ is a non-decreasing (resp. non-increasing) sequence of elements of $O(X)$ then $\mu’(\bigcup O_n)=\sup \mu’(O_n)$ (resp. $\mu’(\bigcap O_n)=\inf \mu’(O_n)$, provided $\bigcap O_n\in O(X)$).

Comment: @AlexRavsky: I, too, suspect something along the lines of what you suggest. After all, this is how the construction works starting from compact subsets (the details may be found in Bourbaki's "Integration" volume). As you know, though, sometimes overlooking just a small detail may ruin the whole construction, so this is why I would like to see it done in more detail. It seems, though, that nobody has done it.